# iOS filtering user apps versus daemons and system processes

Tags: ios, process, pid

So I am using this code to get a list of all processes running on an iOS device:

```
-(NSArray *) getProcesses {
int mib[4] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0};
unsigned int miblen = 4;

size_t size;
int st = sysctl(mib, miblen, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);

struct kinfo_proc * process = NULL;
struct kinfo_proc * newprocess = NULL;

do {

    size += size / 10;
    newprocess = realloc(process, size);

    if (!newprocess){

        if (process){
            free(process);
        }

        return nil;
    }

    process = newprocess;
    st = sysctl(mib, miblen, process, &size, NULL, 0);

} while (st == -1 && errno == ENOMEM);

if (st == 0){

    if (size % sizeof(struct kinfo_proc) == 0){
        unsigned long nprocess = size / sizeof(struct kinfo_proc);

        if (nprocess){

            NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for (long i = nprocess - 1; i >= 0; i--){

                NSString * processID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", process[i].kp_proc.p_pid];
                NSString * processName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", process[i].kp_proc.p_comm];
                NSString *ppid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", process[i].kp_eproc.e_ppid];

                NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:processID, processName, ppid, nil]
                                                                    forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ProcessID", @"ProcessName", @"ppid", nil]];
                [array addObject:dict];
            }

            free(process);
            return array;
        }
    }
}

return nil;
}
```

I thought I would be able to filter by the parent pid since usually daemons get adopted by the init process (pid 1) but according to the output of this code, pretty much all processes including user apps have 1 as their ppid. So either iOS doesn't track this or everyone gets thrown under init (or whatever the BSD equivalent is called). Also I thought about throwing out any processes ending in 'd' like most daemons but there is an obvious problem there. So does anyone have an idea of how you could filter out just user apps rather than system processes?